# Pullback of volume form on $\mathbb{S}^n$ by antipodal map

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Let $F:\mathbb{S}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^n$ be the antipodal map, then it's differential $D_pF:T_p\mathbb{S}^n\rightarrow T_{-p}\mathbb{S}^n$ is given by $X\mapsto -X$. Consider the volume form $dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{n+1}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, and the vector field:
$$X=x^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$$
on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Let $\iota:\mathbb{S}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ bet he inclusion, then:
$$\omega=i^*(X\lrcorner\alpha)$$
is the standard volume form on $\mathbb{S}^n$. Let $v_1,\dots, v_n\in T_p\mathbb{S}^n$ be arbitrary, then:
$$
\begin{align}
(F^*\omega)_p(v_1,\dots, v_n)=&\omega_{-p}(-v_1,\dots, -v_n)\\
=&(-1)^n\alpha_{-p}(X_{-p},v_1,\dots, v_n)
\end{align}
$$
Now, I want to say that since the volume form is constant, we have $\alpha_p=\alpha_{-p}$, and that since $v_1,\dots, v_n$ originally lied $T_p\mathbb{S}^n$ they now lie in $T_p\mathbb{S}^n$ because I have factored out the negative signs. Thus we can write:
$$
\begin{align}
(F^*\omega)_p(v_1,\dots, v_n)=&(-1)^n\alpha_p(-X_p,v_1,\dots, v_n)\\
=&(-1)^{n+1}\omega_p(v_1,\dots,v_n)
\end{align}
$$
so $F^*\omega=(-1)^{n+1}\omega$. Does this make any sense? I always feel uneasy about pulling back my automorphisms...

Edit:

I agree it makes no sense to say that the volume form is constant. How about this:

We have that:
$$X_{-p}=F_*(X_p)$$
where $F$ is regarded as the antipodal map on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, hence:
$$\begin{align}
(F^*\omega)_p(v_1,\dots, v_n)=&\alpha_{-p}(F_*(X_p), -v_1,\dots, -v_n)\\
=&(F^*\alpha)_p(X_p,v_1,\dots, v_n)
\end{align}$$
Now:
$$(F^*\alpha)=d(x^1\circ F)\wedge \cdots d(x^{n+1}\circ F)=(-1)^{n+1}dx^1\wedge\cdots \wedge dx^{n+1}=(-1)^{n+1}\alpha$$
hence:
$$(F^*\omega)_p(v_1,\dots, v_n)
=(-1)^{n+1}\alpha_p(X_p,v_1,\dots, v_n)$$
implying that:
$$(F^*\omega)=(-1)^{n+1}\omega$$
Does this work?

Comment: It does not quite make sense to say the a volume form is constant.

Comment: @ArcticChar see edit.

Comment: Note that this confirms the fact that $\Bbb RP^n$ is orientable if and only if $n$ is odd.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think this only gives one direction immediately though? The other direction requires this fact, but you still need to construct the form, hence my comment on your other answer.

Comment: Yes, I was stipulating that a form invariant under the deck transformation(s) of the covering space descends.

Comment: @TedShifrin is this same idea that a horizontal Ad invariant form on a principal bundle descends to a form with values in adjoint bundle on the base?

Comment: Yes, and more generally, for a smooth fiber bundle, but then you need to differentiate along the fiber. In the discrete case, there's no such differentiation.